# Angular source decoding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm new with Angular and JavaScript, cant decode the method below.Could you help me to understand?

```
  getSalesgroupunitTx(): string {
    if (this . salesgroups !== undefined && this . salesgroupId !== undefined) {
      var salesgroup = this.salesgroups.filter((item, index) => {
        if (item.salesgroupId == this.salesgroupId) return true;
      });、
      this.salesgroupunitTx = salesgroup[0].salesgroupunitTx;
    }
    return this.salesgroupunitTx;
```

there are some materials...

in constructor

```
   this.salesGroupService
    .get()
    .then(outputJson => {
      this.working = false;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(outputJson));
      this.salesgroups = outputJson.salesgroups;
      this.salesgroupId = this.salesgroups[0]['salesgroupId'];
```

in salesGroupService. I'm getting input from APIserver like below

```
put(
    salesgroupId: number,
    salesgroupCd: string,
    salesgroupTx: string,
    salescategoryId: number,
    salesgroupunitTx: string,
    updprogramCd: string
  ): Promise<any> {
    const url = `${environment.baseUrl + this.apiUrl}/${salesgroupId}`;
    const jsonInput = {
      salesgroupCd: salesgroupCd,
      salesgroupTx: salesgroupTx,
      salescategoryId: salescategoryId,
      salesgroupunitTx: salesgroupunitTx,
      updprogramCd: updprogramCd
    };
```

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate in code review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: I didnt know that site, thank you!!